# Core Data Many to Many relation insert data error

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I am having an issue with core data many to many relationship. I have two entity Menus <<---->> Categories. I can insert data on both the entities. But when I tried to establish a relationship between them, I used this code:

```
[menu addToCategoriesObject:catagory];
```

And it crashes with the following error :

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryI addToCategoriesObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8fca680'
```

Your help is appreciated. Also, if there is any good tutorial on Core Data many to many relationship, please share it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`menu` seems to be an `NSDictionary` object. `NSDictionary` does not know the method addToCategoriesObject.

You need to establish the relationship by calling the methods on your generated `NSManagedObject` subclasses, for example something like `addManyCategories:(NSSet *)value`.

Comment: menu is a NSManagedObject subclass object. catagory is also NSManagedObject subclass object. 'addToCategoriesObject' method is CoreDataGeneratedAccessors

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint on the above line and paste the output of `po menu`?

Comment: Also how are you creating your `NSManagedObject`s?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I kept my data in NSDictionary instead of NSManagedObject subclass object. NSDictionary changed its format. So when I tried to add it by addToCategoriesObject method it crashed!!